# Magento 2 Decrease Stock When Order is Placed when Manage Stock is NO

Tags: manage-stock

Currently I have stock management software running

Is it possible to have the Quantity Of Stock decrease when an order is placed whilst having the option to Manage Stock OFF.

Currently I have the Decrease Stock When Order is Placed set to YES and the MANAGE STOCK set to NO however when an order is placed the Quantity of the item does not decrease, it remains the same.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question has all the answers, as you said you have set configuration **MANAGE STOCK** to **NO** which tells magento to not manage (update increase quantity on order cancellation and decrease on successful order placement).

To manage quantity with your software you have to manage it by **API calls(real time)** or csv updates on **regular intervals** using crons.